# Does using rounded numbers decrease CPU usage in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm performing a lot of calculations in javascript. I was wondering if using rounded numbers would decrease CPU usage? When I look at the inner workings of my code using console.log, the numbers have upwards of 15 decimal places.

Comment: It seems this would be very easy to test yourself. What happens when you try? Does the CPU use go down? (Hint: No.)

Comment: good point, but I was hoping to get some technical reasoning as to why it would or would not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. JavaScript does not distinguish between integers and real numbers. It only has double-precision floats.

This means that accuracy will be best with integers or binary fractions (within the range of about 15 significant digits), but actual performance won't vary much, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes highly optimized engines can tell the difference between an integer and a double. For instance 1+1 might use integer math where 1.0+1 might not. Most likely this "integerness" will quickly get lost, functions like Math.pow, Math.sqrt, etc. will likely lose the property. However I would not rely on this behavior and even rounded number might not have this effect (i.e. they might still be floats after rounding).

Also, as an aside, there's probably so much overhead in the JS engine that the difference between using a float and an integer would not be that big (given that the difference is maybe a factor of 2-3 on the processor itself and the overhead is probably at least a factor of 10).